# Second delegate in Class possible in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, uipageviewcontroller

I have a class that I want to receive data from a custom subclass of `UIPageViewController`.  For this purpose, I have defined a protocol as normal in the class I want to receive the information:

```
protocol GetMyIndexDelegate: class {
    func getIndex()
}

class LandingPageViewController: UIViewController, GetMyIndexDelegate {

func getIndex() {
    print("IT GOT CALLED")
}}
```

and then in the class which is to send the information:

```
class pageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

weak var delegate2: GetMyIndexDelegate?

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if (completed && finished) {
        if let currentVC = pageViewController.viewControllers?.last {
            let index = vcArr.index(of: currentVC)
            delegate2?.getIndex()
        }
    }
}
```

I had to use `delegate2` here because there is already a delegate `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` and if I use `delegate` I get an error

> 'cannot overide property with type UIPageViewControllerDelegate'

However when I run the app and scroll through the pages, the function `getIndex` is not called.

I'm not sure if you can even have 2 delegates within the same class. I  can't see another way of running the `getIndex` function each time the page is scrolled and the index changes.

Comment: You can create two different Delegates and use it, you can't use single delegate at two different places.

Comment: that is what i have done.  but the getIndex function is not getting called.

Comment: Yep, the problem is likely that `delegate2` was `nil`. Unrelated, I'd suggest a more meaningful name than `delegate2`. Perhaps `indexDelegate` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `delegate2` is nil at the line where you try to call `getIndex`. Since `delegate2` is a `weak` property, it will not keep an object alive. If you don't have some other strong reference to the object, then it will be deallocated and set the `delegate2` property to nil.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can have as many delegates you want. But you might have a slight confusion on usage. Is `delegate2` `nil` ? Are you assigning instance of some class which confirms to `GetMyIndexDelegate` ? Please verify that first

Have a look at here

[Delegate Example](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/)